# Сочетаемость слова "конгруэнтен"

Tags: словосочетания

Возможно ли словосочетание *"конгруэнтен в своих нравах"?*

И какие еще словосочетания могут быть со словом "конгруэнтен"?

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае слово "нравы" применено к индивиду, в то время как во множественном числе оно применяется к социальным группам (обычаи, особенности коллективного поведения, нормы морали); применительно к отдельному человеку правильнее говорить о его "нраве" (эмоциональных особенностях характера). Вряд ли это сочетаемо с "конгруэнтностью", термином из области психологии, заимствованным наряду с более широко разошедшейся "адекватностью". Определение из Большого психологического словаря (2003):

> Конгруэнтность (он англ. congruence) – открытость, честность.
>   Конгруэнтным называют человека, который сознает и принимает
>   чувства/ощущения, которые испытывает, может назвать их и выразить в
>   поведении нетравмирующим для окружающих способом.

[Конгруэнтность | psychologies.ru](http://www.psychologies.ru/glossary/10/kongruentnost/)

Более подробное толкование есть в википедии:

[Конгруэнтность (психология) | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Термин "конгруэнтность" чаще всего употребляется как самодостаточный, но можно выделить напр. сочетание "*конгруэнтность в общении*" (адекватность поведения человека во взаимодействии с другим, уважение его автономии, принятие во внимание его индивидуально-личностных особенностей, его состояний и переживаний):

[Проблема конгруэнтности в христианском
общении.pdf | psyjournals.ru](http://psyjournals.ru/files/68068/23_Gavrilova_psyedu_1_2014.pdf)

Comment: Во как. А я даже по-иному и растолковал. Ну тогда тем более не стоит злоупотреблять им.

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке "конгруэнтность", "конгруэнтный" применяется исключительно как математический термин. Использование его в других сочетаниях порождает разве что комический эффект.

И даже если смысл высказывания в общем-то понятен (умерен, равноудален во взглядах), такое сочетание лучше не использовать всерьез.

Если не ошибаюсь, раньше это слово могло использоваться шире, но сейчас даже иное, не математическое понимание, полностью утрачено носителями.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Говоря о нравах, надо понимать, во-первых, что они имеют значение для той или иной социальной группы. Нравы отражают моральные ценности **общества**. И второе: словосочетание это (*конгруэнтен в своих нравах*), даже если остро необходимо и понятно автору, потребует десятка родных и для связки — иностранных слов, чтобы также понималось и принималось другими.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Можно сказать: конгруэнтен **по своему нраву**, но здесь семантика не совсем точна, более удачный  вариант - конгруэнтен **по своему характеру, поведению.**

Нрав бывает тихий, спокойный, скромный, добрый, веселый, это обобщенная характеристика, в нашем же случае речь идет о конкретной личностной особенности.

**Из словаря:**

КОНГРУЭНТНЫЙ,  [от лат. congruens (congruentis) - совпадающий] Матем. **Совпадающий** при наложении; равновеликий (о геометрических фигурах). <Конгруэнтность, -и; ж. К. геометрических фигур.

НРАВ, 1. **Совокупность** душевных, психических свойств; характер. Крутой н. Добрый, весёлый н. Она была нрава тихого и скромного. // Строптивый, упрямый характер; норов. 2. обычно мн.: нравы, -ов. Обычаи, уклад жизни. Деревенские нравы.